# once exported, java can't display images

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I made a project named JavaProject in netbeans, when I exported it in a flashdrive the images were not loaded while the other functionalities worked fine. I figured maybe it is beacause of the path defined. I used the primary method of `<label>.setIcon(new ImageIcon(<path of the image>)` method.

```
imglabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\java project\\photo.jpg");
```

What I think is maybe I have to do something in the src directory but I don't know what.

Comment: have you tried to use the resources folder ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what i can see your paths are referring to C: , I assume you exported your java project as jar file, and now code is referring images which resides inside jar file.
Any resource inside jar file can not be accessed with absolute paths.

there are two options

1. Either keep your images outside jar and refer their path from environment variable/external property file etc
2. You can also access them as resource in jar something like

   InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("test/resources/MyImage.jpg");

I would prefer first one ,as I am not sure about your use case

Note: Edited as suggested by @mark

Comment: You might want to flesh out your answer a little bit. Where will the OP have to store the image files and how can he reference them in the code so that he can access them both from Netbeans and the exported jar file? Then again, I still assume this question is going to get closed as a duplicate, so it's up to you to decide how detailed you really want to be.

Comment: I am fairly new to programming in general. What I know is - This, being an absolute path, works without any problem. However, since this program will be running on different machines, I'm trying to figure out how to make use of a relative path in order to access the path above.
The path defined here is for C: drive which doesn't make sense. I'm only asking for an alternate method.

Comment: Edited as advised by @Mark